# some bug which i can not find for two days (output is not as expected)

Tags: python, numpy, storage, multidimensional-array

```
from numpy import *
import time
import pylab as plt

a=zeros([10,10])
b=ones([10,10])
dx=dy=0.1
x,y = mgrid[:1:dx,:1:dy]
def add(a,b):
  a[1:-1,1:-1]=a[1:-1,1:-1]+b[1:-1,1:-1]

  data=0
  print(data)
for i in range(4):
#data.append(a)
    print (a)
    add(a,b)
```

---

> above is the illustration code to clarify the problem I encountered.
>    What I what the code prints is:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
[ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
[ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
[ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
[ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
[ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
[ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
[ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  0.]
[ 0.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  0.]
[ 0.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  0.]
[ 0.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  0.]
[ 0.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  0.]
[ 0.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  0.]
[ 0.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  0.]
[ 0.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  0.]
[ 0.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  0.]
[ 0.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  0.]
[ 0.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  0.]
[ 0.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  0.]
[ 0.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  0.]
[ 0.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  0.]
[ 0.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

> however the code outputs:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

> so is there solution to this kind of problem?
>
> Thank you~
>
> someone has offered the below solution :

```
from numpy import*
import time
import pylab as plt

dx=dy=0.1
x,y = mgrid[:1:dx,:1:dy]

data=[]
for i in range(4):
    a=zeros([10,10])
    b=ones([10,10])
    a[1:-1,1:-1] = b[1:-1,1:-1]*i
    data.append(a)

for k in range(4):
     print(data[k])
```

> however this one is not a typical recipe for this type of problem. That is because if [add]  function I use or maybe the a, b array in the example changes, this solution will lose its effect

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. I do not get the second output you displace [[0. 4. 4. .....]] with either code snippet. What is the desired output of your code?

Comment: Your first code works exactly as you expect it on my system. Are you sure you are running the same code you have posted?

Comment: Thank you guys, the problems has been solved. The answer below serves as a good solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other words, this code gives the desired output:

```
for _ in range(4):
    print(a)
    add(a, b)
```

But this doesn't:

```
data = []
for _ in range(4):
    data.append(a)
    add(a, b)

for d in data: 
    print(d)
```

Let's look at a simple example first, that will help you to understand what is going on:

```
In [184]: a = zeros(3)

In [185]: a
Out[185]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])

In [186]: b = a

In [187]: b[0] = 99

In [188]: print(a)
[ 99.   0.   0.]
```

You see what happens? We make an array `b` the same as array `a` and then modifying array `b` also changes array `a`!

This happens, because actually there is only 1 array object! The "variables" `a` and `b` are just two names for the same underlying object. So we can modify the array by using name `b` and we will see the changes also if we use name `a`, because it's the same array.

The same happens if you append `a` to a list. The list contains references to objects. But in your case the references are all to the same single object!

One way to solve this is by creating a new array object each time we append the array to the list:

```
data = []
for _ in range(4):
    data.append(a.copy())
    add(a, b)
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer， It really helps~        there is also 'reference' conception in python same as c++, still a lot to learn~